# How to throw a user-defined exception in java's function and catch them elsewhere?

Tags: java, exception

How can I catch this kind of exception in java?

```
throw new Exception("Error") {
    // Here is what makes the exception user-defined.
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Here is your user-defined exception!";
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Catch them elsewhere"??

Comment: This is not a user defined exception.

Comment: @SureshAtta - Yes it is.  It is just not a >>useful<< user defined exception.

Comment: May be poorly designed exception with no use.

Comment: It means that to catch the user defined exception in the outer function.

Comment: @md612 - I don't understand what you are saying.  Please show us the Java code that illustrates what you mean by that.  (And I suspect that you won't be able to ... because it is not possible in any useful sense ... as per the answers below.)

Comment: You completely changed the question. Now you have a named custom exception class, but you can't catch the exception, since you are throwing it at the `main` method, so there's no outer method that can catch it.

Comment: @md612 - Don't vandalize your Question.  I have rolled it back. If you have a >>different<< question, ask it as a new Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is create an anonymous subclass of `Exception`.  The only way you can catch it is to catch `Exception`.

Hint: what you are doing is pointless.  User-defined exceptions are only *useful* if they are normal (not anonymous) classes.  You have to be able to **name** them to catch them ... and if you cannot catch an exception (independently of its superclass) then it serves no purpose.

---

Maybe what you are trying to do might be done by declaring the exception as a private static nested class. That stops it from being caught outside of the enclosing class. But it can still be named and hence caught in a method declared within the enclosing class.

Comment: But what if I only want to capture that specific kind of exception, not all exceptions.

Comment: Well you can't do it with an exception defined like that.  You need to define a proper >>named<< exception class that extends (say) `Exception`.

Comment: I understand now.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an anonymous sub-class of Exception, it has no name, so you can only catch it with a general catch clause:

```
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Sometimes using an anonymous class instance is not a good idea. This is a good example of where anonymous classes should **not** be used. You should define a regular custom exception class, which would allow you to have a specific catch clause.

Comment: Ooops I edited your answer by accident.  Rolled back.  Sorry.